# Does Green Lord's Gift effectively make all heal spells roll max on the Warlock?

Tags: dnd-5e, warlock, healing, unearthed-arcana, eldritch-invocations

[Unearthed Arcana: Warlock & Wizard](http://media.wizards.com/2017/dnd/downloads/20170213_Wizrd_Wrlck_UAv2_i48nf.pdf) includes the eldritch invocation *Green Lord's Gift* for warlocks, which reads:

> **Green Lord’s Gift**
>
> *Prerequisite: The Archfey patron*
>
> The Green Lord oversees a verdant realm of
> everlasting summer. Your soul is linked to his
> power. Whenever you regain hit points, you treat
> any dice rolled to determine the hit points you
> regain as having rolled their maximum value.

If I take this invocation, does it only benefit healing from resting and potions, or would healing spells also be maximized? For example, my Warlock is multi-classing as a Cleric, so I have [*healing word*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/healing-word). If I cast *healing word* on myself, would the roll effectively be (4 x spell level) + modifier?

Comment: Note for future readers: Green Lord's Gift ended up being published in Xanathar's as a Pact of the Chain-only invocation (all patron prerequisites were removed) titled "Gift of the Ever-Living Ones".

Answer (score 15, accepted):

## Yes

Using the 5E rule of specific over general, **Green Lord's Gift** does not call out specific ways of regaining hit points. The general case is "any". It doesn't hurt that **Green Lord's Gift** uses the word "any", either.

---

<sub>**Green Lord's Gift** was published as  [**Gift of the Ever-Living Ones**](https://www.dndbeyond.com/classes/warlock#EldritchInvocations-388) in *Xanathar's Guide to Everything*, p. 57. The prerequisites have changed, but the effect is the same:</sub>

> <sub>*Prerequisite: Pact of the Chain feature*</sub>
>
> <sub>Whenever you regain hit points while your familiar is within 100 feet of you, treat any dice rolled to determine the hit points you regain as having rolled their maximum value for you.</sub>

Comment: Would this Maximize Vampiric Touch because Vampiric touch "heals" you?

Comment: @VoromirKadien No, because Vampiric Touch doesn't have a roll for healing, it has a roll for damage. The healing has a mathematical relationship to the damage dealt, but it is not rolled.

Answer (score 13):

## Yes

This works with healing spells.  It doesn't say it doesn't, so it does.  Healing spells used on you (whether you cast them or not) may cause you to regain a variable quantity of hitpoints, and this ability maximizes the roll involved in that hitpoint gain.