# Does the warlock's Gift of the Ever-Living Ones eldritch invocation work with potions or healing spells cast on you by others?

Tags: dnd-5e, warlock, healing, eldritch-invocations

The description of the warlock's Gift of the Ever-Living Ones [eldritch invocation](https://www.dndbeyond.com/classes/warlock#EldritchInvocations-388) (XGtE, p. 57) says:

> *Prerequisite: Pact of the Chain feature*
>
> Whenever you regain hit points while your familiar is within 100 feet of you, treat any dice rolled to determine the hit points you regain as having rolled their maximum value for you.

I'm trying to plan out my Warlock build. I'm curious if the invocation Gift of the Ever-Living Ones allows you to take the max die roll for potions and healing spells cast upon you by others.

The wording seems a bit vague to me, and so I'm a little confused.

Comment: Related question about the UA version of the invocation: [Does Green Lord's Gift effectively make all heal spells roll max on the Warlock?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/102359/does-green-lords-gift-effectively-make-all-heal-spells-roll-max-on-the-warlock)

Answer (score 26, accepted):

## The wording is not vague

You always take the maximum value of any dice rolled to heal you.  If someone casts a spell that heals 2d8+3 hp to everyone in 30 feet and it affects you and they roll a 3 and a 1 you heal 19 hp and everyone else affected heals 7.  You treat dice rolled to heal you as if they rolled their maximum value for you.  The source of the die in question does not matter.

Comment: Thanks! I guess I just needed confirmation and chose my words poorly. I just couldn't believe that it was that good.

Comment: Yep. Specifically, the wording avoids this confusion by saying "any dice rolled to determine the hit points you regain", rather than "any dice *you roll*". It applies to any dice whose direct purpose is to determine how much HP you regain: healing spells, hit dice, *potions of healing*, and any other dice rolled to determine healing. (Note that [it doesn't work for *vampiric touch*](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/123770/33569), as the dice rolled for that spell determine the damage and the resulting healing is simply derived from that value.)